# Arranging 15 boys and 15 girls in a row

Tags: combinatorics

> A boy and a girl are sitting next to each other on a bench in the
> park. A group of their friends is passing by. One by one, each person
> from the group comes over and sits between two people who are already
> on the bench. We say that a boy in the group is special if, when he
> comes to the bench, he sits immediately between two girls. We also say
> that a girl in the group is special if, when she comes to the bench,
> she sits immediately between two boys. Eventually, when everyone is
> seated, there are 15 boys and 15 girls on the bench, alternating. How
> many of them are special?

I tried to list out all of the cases, but I realized that the method would take too much time and I would likely miss a case. Is there a good way to start this problem that doesn't involve crunching numbers?

Comment: The wording of the problem suggests uniqueness. Do we know this is the case? If so, then we just need to play the situation out once and count the specials and that’s our answer.

Comment: Or we could prove uniqueness, probably by induction.

Comment: @RobertShore Induction would be difficult, because an alternating arrangement of $n$ boys and $n$ girls doesn't have to be produced by taking an alternating arrangement of $n-1$ boys and $n-1$ girls and then adding a boy and girl each.

Comment: Can a person become special only on **immediately** sitting between two of the opposite sex, and not afterwards  by subsequent people's seating ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the number of people who are sitting to the left of someone of the opposite sex. Show that every arrival of a special person raises this number by 2, and that every arrival of a non-special person leaves this number unchanged. This number is 1 at the beginning and 29 at the end.

Comment: But there aren't 29 people sitting next to the left of someone of the opposite sex?

Comment: Think about how this number changes as people arrive one by one.